# #145 - Table '.\phpmyadmin\pma_recent' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed Xampp on my Windows 7, and everything was working fine.. I had about 7 WP Websites/Databases setup, all working fine.

Then I got a note displaying at the bottom of one of the pages, saying that I didn't have a root password set, and was at risk.  So I stupidly changed all three root users's passwords (ie: root:1  root:localhost  root 127.0.0.1).  Note: I changed all three to the same password.

Or course that broke Apache server totally.  After research, I found that I should change the config.inc.php and add the new password there, and then restart the Server.  Thankfully that worked!

But now.. on all my databases and for all tables inside of those DBs.. no matter which table I select to look at, I get this error:

```
Could not save recent table!
#145 - Table '.\phpmyadmin\pma_recent' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

All the tables seem to display correctly, it just shows this as an error at the top of the results page when I click on any table name.  If I click on the same table name again, it displays without the error.. but if I go to another table, then come back to the previous table, the error will display again, etc, etc, etc..

It appears that the websites are still functioning.. and that the database tables can still display with or without the error showing.. and I appear to even be able to edit the tables, but I am not confident that all is well with the xampp install now.

Since this error started displaying straight after the changing of and the fixing of the root password, I have a feeling it is related.  (If it makes any difference, under Users.. I still have the following users listed as not having a password set: "any"  and "pma".)  Does the PMA need to be set to the same password as the root to work properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it probably isn't related to the change of your root password.

Try opening up that table (by expanding "phpmyadmin" in the navigation area then clicking on the "pma_recent" table name). Go to the Operations tab and click the "Repair table" link (which is under the "Table maintenance" heading). This should tell MySQL to repair the table and should clear up your error message.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!!  I had been trying to go through and repair all of the tables from each of my wordpress Databases that I had created on the Xampp server.. but of course that wasn't working.  I hadn't found the actual PMA_RECENT table at that point, because I hadn't thought to look at the tables that Xampp had created.  Your instructions worked perfectly.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond.. saved me hours of work!  (BTW: If you have any ideas of why it got corrupted in the first place, I would appreciate knowing for future reference!)

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad it helped. I'm not really sure what would cause this problem, but http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15079/33241 has some thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

You could do what was suggested by "Isaac Bennetch" or could alternatively run the following to repair the corrupted table:

```
REPAIR TABLE 'table_name';
```